# Update xamarin app via app center distribute : Problem while parsing package

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-app-center

We have made an android app using Xamarin and make use of microsoft appcenter build and distribute, we migrated this app from using HockeyApp.

Appcenter allows us to make a QR code which people can then scan and they can install the application this way, this works fine. Another way users can install the application is by using the app center app, this also works.

However when we push out an update we start to get issues. We have allowed using in app updates so when we push a new version a pop up will show in the app requiring that you update it. There is a download button available.  Clicking this will start the download. After the download is finished a screen is showed with the text 'Staging app' and the following error message : "There was a problem while parsing the package." This happens both using the app center app or the QR code to install the app. We can also install a new version using the microsoft app center app, in this case it does work but we would like the in app updates to work properly too.

How can we get this to work so that users can also do in app updates where the new version can actually be installed? The code to activate distribute is as follows :

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            Forms.Init(this, bundle);
            ContextMenuViewRenderer.Preserve();
            appVersion = "" + this.PackageManager.GetPackageInfo(ApplicationContext.PackageName, 0).VersionName;

            if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.Lollipop)
            {
                Window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.DrawsSystemBarBackgrounds);
            }

            AppCenter.Start(_appCenterId,
                   typeof(Analytics), typeof(Crashes), typeof(Distribute));
            CheckForUpdates();

}
private void CheckForUpdates()
{
      Distribute.SetEnabledAsync(true);
}

private void UnregisterManagers()
{
      Distribute.SetEnabledAsync(false);
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

> Problem while parsing package

About this problem,

- You need to check whether the `apk` file has been downloaded fully first. Check the size of downloaded apk file is the same with the server.
- Second, you need to check whether the name of `apk` file is legal, such as can not contain space char.
- Third, check the `android:minSdkVersion` of **AndroidManifest** is higher than your current environment.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the reply. If I manually install the package i dont have any problem so that seems to rule out option 2 and 3 since i would think in that cause it would fail too. Meaning that likely the APK is not fully downloaded. However I don't understand why this would be the case since I use the automatic updates from microsoft  appcenter.

Comment: @Jens Okey, do you test in the same device? And you can share the device logs here, then will be helpful to check where problem is.